# Get the highest odds from the last update

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these tables in a PostgreSQL database:

**bookmakers**

```
-----------------------
| id   | name         |
-----------------------
| 1    | Unibet       |
-----------------------
| 2    | 888          |
-----------------------
```

**odds**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| id  | odds_type  | odds_index  | bookmaker_id | created_at        |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1   | 1          | 1.55        | 1            | 2012-06-02 10:30  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2   | 2          | 3.22        | 2            | 2012-06-02 10:30  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 3   | X          | 3.00        | 1            | 2012-06-02 10:30  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 4   | 2          | 1.25        | 1            | 2012-05-27 09:30  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 5   | 1          | 2.30        | 2            | 2012-05-27 09:30  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 6   | X          | 2.00        | 2            | 2012-05-27 09:30  |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I am trying to query is the following:

Give me the 1/X/2 odds from the **latest update** (created_at) from ALL bookmakers  and from that last update, give me the **highest odds** for **each odds_type** ('1', '2', 'X').

On my website I display them as:

```
Best odds right now:   1   |   X   |   2
                     --------------------
                     2.30  |  3.00 | 3.22
```

I have to first get the latest, because the odds from the update from yesterday are no longer valid. Then from that last update, I have - in this case - 2 odds from 2 different bookmakers, so I need to get the best one for type '1','2','X'.

Pseudo SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT MAX(odds_index) WHERE odds_type = '1' ORDER BY created_at DESC, odds_index DESC
```

But that doesn't work, because I would always get the latest odds (and not the highest/best from those latest)

I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: What do you mean from the "last update"?  The last update for each bookmaker?

Comment: Indeed, the last update "round" where I visit each bookmaker's XML feed to get the latest odds for football matches. Basically that update round voids all older odds, but I want to keep them for other queries (odds trends for last xx days)

Answer (score 2):

Subqueries to the rescue!

```
select o1.odds_type, max(o1.odds_index)
from odds o1
inner join (select odds_type, max(created_at) as created_at
            from odds group by odds_type) o2
on o1.odds_type = o2.odds_type
and o1.created_at = o2.created_at
group by o1.odds_type
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47df4/3

Answer (score 0):

Your words "from the last update" contradict your example.  Here are two methods.

To get from last update, how about getting the max created_at date aka last update and then using it for the rest.

```
declare @max_date date
select @max_date = max(created_at) from odds
select odds_type, odds_index
from odds
where created_at = @max_date
```

Or to match your example

```
select odds_type, odds_index
from odds
group by odds_type
having created_at = max(created_at)
```

Note: Different DBMS give different results depending on the select columns and whether there are more columns than in the group by clause.